# For search queries can I force all search to use AND instead of OR?

Tags: magento2

when I search for "bird food" the results that shows up would display all products with the keyword bird OR food so that "fish food" as well as "bird food" would also show up.  My question is: is there anyway to force the search to use AND instead of OR?  for example someone searching bird food would only display bird food and nothing else.  thanks!

Comment: What is your magento version? Which search engine do you use?

Comment: Hi, 2.1.1 II'm current using - I have searchsuite from mageworx.